# How to fix weirdly perfect testing scores in machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest, decision-tree, knn

I am really new in programming, especially, in machine learning. Currently, I am training my dataset and I am using KNN, random forest, and decision tree as my algorithms. However, my accuracy, precision, recall, and f1 scores in random forest and decision tree are all 1.0, which means something is wrong. On the other hand, my KNN scores are low (Accuracy: 0.892 Recall: 0.452 Precision: 0.824 F1-score: 0.584).

I already cleaned and split my dataset for training and testing, and imputed (median) my dataset, so I am really confused as to why the results are like this. What can I do to fix this?

P.S. I am not really sure how to ask questions here, so if I am lacking any information necessary, just tell me.

```
dataset image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FR1K.png
distribution of dataset: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uZzN.png

        #Convert 0's to NaN
        columns = ["Age", "Race", "Marital Status", "T Stage", "N Stage", 
        "6th Stage", "Grade", "A Stage", "Tumor Size", "Estrogen Status", 
        "Progesterone Status", "Regional Node Examined", "Reginol Node 
        Positive", "Survival Months", "Status"]
        data[columns] = data[columns].replace({'0':np.nan, 0:np.nan})

        #imputing using median
        imp_median.fit(data.values)
        imp_median.fit(data.values)
        data_median = imp_median.transform(data.values)
        data_median = pd.DataFrame(data_median)
        data_median.columns =["Age", "Race", "Marital Status", "T Stage ", 
        "N Stage", "6th Stage", "Grade", "A Stage", "Tumor Size", "Estrogen 
        Status", "Progesterone Status", "Regional Node Examined", "Reginol 
        Node Positive", "Survival Months", "Status"]
        
        #scaling data median
        minmaxScale  = MinMaxScaler()
        X = minmaxScale.fit_transform(data_median.values)
        transformedDF = minmaxScale.transform(X)
        data_transformedDF = pd.DataFrame(X)
        data_transformedDF.columns =["Age", "Race", "Marital Status", "T 
        Stage ", "N Stage", "6th Stage", "Grade", "A Stage", "Tumor Size", 
        "Estrogen Status", "Progesterone Status", "Regional Node Examined", 
        "Reginol Node Positive", "Survival Months", "Status"]

        #splitting the dataset
        features = data_transformedDF.drop(["Status"], axis=1)
        outcome_variable = data_transformedDF["Status"]
        x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, 
        outcome_variable, test_size=0.20, random_state=7)

        #cross validation
        def cross_validation(model, _X, _y, _cv=10):
                '''
                Function to perform 10 Folds Cross-Validation
                Parameters
                model: Python Class, default=None
                This is the machine learning algorithm to be used for 
                training.
                _X: array
                This is the matrix of features (age, race, etc).
                _y: array
                This is the target variable (1 - Dead, 0 - Alive).
                cv: int, default=10
                Determines the number of folds for cross-validation.
       
                Returns
                The function returns a dictionary containing the metrics 
                'accuracy', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1' for 
                training/validation set.
                '''
             _scoring = ['accuracy', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1']
             results = cross_validate(estimator=model,
                               X=_X,
                               y=_y,
                               cv=_cv,
                               scoring=_scoring,
                               return_train_score=True)
      
             return {"Training Accuracy scores": 
                     results['train_accuracy'], "Mean Training                           
                     Accuracy":results['train_accuracy'].mean()*100,
                     "Mean Training Precision": 
                     results['train_precision'].mean(),
                     "Mean Training Recall": 
                     results['train_recall'].mean(),
                     "Mean Training F1 Score": 
                     results['train_f1'].mean(),
                     }

        #KNN
        knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
        cross_validation(knn, x_train, y_train, 10)

        #DecisionTree
        from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
        dtc = DecisionTreeClassifier()
        cross_validation(dtc, x_train, y_train, 10)

        #RandomForest
        from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
        rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
        cross_validation(rfc, x_train, y_train, 10)

        # Test predictions for dtc
        dtc_fitted = dtc.fit(x_train, y_train)
        y_pred = dtc_fitted.predict(x_test)
        print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
        print('Accuracy: %.3f' % accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) +
              ' Recall: %.3f' % recall_score(y_test, y_pred)  +
              ' Precision: %.3f' % precision_score(y_test, y_pred) +
              ' F1-score: %.3f' % f1_score(y_test, y_pred))\

        # Test predictions for rfc
        rfc_fitted = rfc.fit(x_train, y_train)
        y_pred = rfc_fitted.predict(x_test)
        print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
        print('Accuracy: %.3f' % accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) +
              ' Recall: %.3f' % recall_score(y_test, y_pred)  +
              ' Precision: %.3f' % precision_score(y_test, y_pred) +
              ' F1-score: %.3f' % f1_score(y_test, y_pred))

        # Test predictions for knn
        knn_fitted = knn.fit(x_train, y_train)
        y_pred = knn_fitted.predict(x_test)
        print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
        print('Accuracy: %.3f' % accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) +
              ' Recall: %.3f' % recall_score(y_test, y_pred)  +
              ' Precision: %.3f' % precision_score(y_test, y_pred) +
              ' F1-score: %.3f' % f1_score(y_test, y_pred))

**For KNN**
 'Mean Training Accuracy': 90.2971947134574,
 'Mean Training Precision': 0.8457275536528337,
 'Mean Training Recall': 0.44194341372912804,
 'Mean Training F1 Score': 0.5804614758695162

  test predictions for knn
  Accuracy: 0.872 Recall: 0.323 Precision: 0.707 F1-score: 0.443
 
**For Decision Tree**
 'Mean Training Accuracy': 100.0,
 'Mean Training Precision': 1.0,
 'Mean Training Recall': 1.0,
 'Mean Training F1 Score': 1.0

 test predictions for dtc:
 Accuracy: 0.850 Recall: 0.528 Precision: 0.523 F1-score: 0.525

**For Random Forest**
 'Mean Training Accuracy': 99.99309630652398,
 'Mean Training Precision': 1.0,
 'Mean Training Recall': 0.9995454545454546,

 test predictions for rtc:
 Accuracy: 0.896 Recall: 0.449 Precision: 0.803 F1-score: 0.576

        from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
        smote = SMOTE()
        # Oversample the training data
        X_train_resampled, y_train_resampled = smote.fit_resample(x_train, 
        y_train)

I ran knn, rfc, and dtc again after running the code for smote
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be a technical issue with the code but rather with something known as target leakage.

That is one of the features in your model is recorded after your label has occurred. For example if you are predicting if the patient is going to die vs not to die, and there is a survival date field, then most models can perfectly predict the outcome.

KNN is a bit different because it is a memorization model - it doesn't learn the relationship between the variable and label. So if it hasn't seen an observation before, it won't give perfect prediction even in the presence of target leakage.